# Execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec to run an exe as admin

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my Windows Selenium Java project I am trying to run a AutoHotKey exe, but the execution of the exe needs to be done as admin.
How would I run the following as admin?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Scripts\\selectFile-emailmsg.exe");
```

Thanks.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` much better. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026393/read-stdout-of-runas-child-process-started-by-processbuilder-or-defaultexecuto) out

Comment: I tried ProcessBuilder but the exe wouldn't run.
I ended up using,
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd runas /user:administrator /savecred /c start \"\" \"C:\\Scripts\\selectFile-open1jpg.exe\"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd runas /user:administrator /savecred /c start \"\" \"C:\\Scripts\\selectFile-open1jpg.exe\"");
```

Comment: check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) of that method: "**Deprecated.**
This method is error-prone and should not be used, the corresponding method [`exec(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) or [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) should be used instead. ..."